# How to reference Java Object classes in separate folders

Tags: java, object

I have a Main class. I also have another class I have made (call it the "Runner" class). I would like to, however, have more Runner classes (the difference between them being modifications to each respective Runner class by other people). Would it be possible to have each Runner class in separate folders and have the folders in the same directory as the Main class, and then reference the Runner objects in the Main class as if they were a class in the same directory as the Main class?

Comment: What? Why not make Runner take a identifier and create an instance at runtime? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes.  You can always declare any variable or reference any class using a full type name (that is, the class name prepended with the package name).  But WHY??

Comment: You can dynamically load classes at runtime through the `Classloader` API

Comment: What I intend to use this knowledge for is testing different people's algorithms on a problem: escaping a maze. I have a Main class and Runner class. The contestants would modify the Runner class with their own algorithm to escape the maze. I simply would like to set up my Main class so that I can look at multiple different variances of the Runner class with the different contestants' algorithms in a single execution of the program.

Comment: In that case, what you _really_ want to do is to have an `interface` that the various people's classes will implement.  The type for any variable that refers to the objects of these classes will be the interface, not the class.  Use the `forName` and `newInstance` methods of the `Class` class to instantiate the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this question strikes me like you're viewing Java like php or ruby, etc which isn't quite accurate.  With Java, each class has what's called a "Fully Qualified Name" which is derived from the folder it's stored in (like Python).  Because Java is compiled, you tell the *compiler* where to find the code needed to compile a java file, rather than putting a reference to those needed files in the top of the file (like a `require` statement in php) which would be an instruction to the *interpreter*.

Say for instance you had a structure like this:

```
src/
  Main.java
  /runner1
     SomeRunner.java
  /runner2
     SomeOtherRunner.java
```

Main.java

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     //use SomeRunner
     runner1.SomeRunner.run();
     //use SomeOtherRunner
     runner2.SomeOtherRunner.run();

  }
}
```

SomeRunner.java

```
package runner1;
public class SomeRunner{
   public void run(){ ... }
}
```

SomeOtherRunner.java

```
package runner2;
public class SomeOtherRunner{
   public void run(){ ... }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use imports:

Main.java

```
import runner1.SomeRunner;
import runner2.SomeOtherRunner;
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args){
     //use SomeRunner
     SomeRunner.run();
     //use SomeOtherRunner
     SomeOtherRunner.run();

  }
}
```

In this example, I chose arbitrary package names (`runner1` and `runner`) which is technically fine.  However, best practices state that your package names should be the reverse domain name of your project (i.e. `com.myproject`) to avoid collisions with other libraries etc.  You can read more about that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html). When you compile your `Main` class, you will need to supply the `SomeRunner` and `SomeOtherRunner` files to the compiler so it knows where to find them.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but I do not think this would exactly fit what I had in mind to do. I want to be able to treat each of the Runner classes as a single Runner class,  essentially be able to store them all in a data structure, such as an array or ArrayList, and use a for loop to see how they all run in a single execution. I tried to do that with your suggestions and I even experimented with them but to no avail. Are there any suggestions you would have for solving this?